# How can you calculate the module of a gear?

Tags: trigonometry

How can you calculate the module of a gear, knowing only the space between the teeth, the number of teeth and the contact angle?

On the website "http://woodgears.ca/gear_cutting/template.html" Can create gears informing the space between the teeth, the number of teeth and the contact angle. I have little knowledge in gear, but I saw that almost all calculations are based on the module."http://www.qtcgears.com/Q410/PDF/techsec1.pdf". I wonder how it is possible to calculate the module only with the space between the teeth (tooth spacing), the number of teeth on gear and the contact angle(deg).

[image]

I need understand how is possible found this data only with the information available.

Comment: The scribd link doesn't work, and the words "engrenavem radius" seem to be unique to your post itself.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Sorry, i edit the question and the link.